# UNITY PREFABS DOESN'T SHOW UP IN GAME TAB

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, game-engine

[image]

As you can see in the screenshoot I can't see prefabs in the game tab but only in the editor. I have made a simple function for shooting(not finished yet), it works fine, it spawns the prefabs but i can't see them in the game tab, I have already tried changing the Sorting Layer, move the camera, change Z position but nothing appen.

This is my code:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerAttack : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    float delayBetweenShots = 0.4f;

    float timePassedSinceLast = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        timePassedSinceLast = delayBetweenShots;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Aiming();
        Shooting();
    }

    void Aiming()
    {
        var objectPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
        var dir = Input.mousePosition - objectPos;

        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,Mathf.Atan2(-dir.x, dir.y) * Mathf.Rad2Deg));
    }

    void Shooting()
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) && timePassedSinceLast >= delayBetweenShots)
        {
            GameObject bullet = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("bullet"), transform.position, transform.rotation);
            timePassedSinceLast = 0f;

        }
        else
        {
            timePassedSinceLast += Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do they appear in the hierarchy? what happens if you go to the scene view and click on them and focus on them, are they perhaps appearing inside something else? you dont seem to give them direction and movement do they have the right sort order to not be behind other things like the player, the buildings

Comment: Like bugfinder said, run the game, shoot some prefabs, pause the editor while some are in flight and double click on one of  the clones to zoom up close to it. do you just see the transform gizmos?

Comment: note while paused you can hide other things to check the instantiated object has body

Comment: maybe they are in a layer where your camera isnt including that layer. Check which layer they are and the camera culling settings.

Comment: Yes they appear in the hierarchy and in the editor but not  in game

Comment: As it is a 2D game, check your bullet GO z position, maybe they exists behind your camera

Comment: As I said, you need to check its not behind other things... so, as mentinoned above, pause the game, hide player, buildings and I bet they appear.. in which case, its the sort order or layers

Comment: In general **DON'T USE RESOURCES** at all. See [Best Practices for the Resources System](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)! Rather but your prefab in a normal folder and use `[SerializeField] private GameObject prefab;` and drag your prefab in here via the Inspector!

Comment: I like BugFinder's suggestions, particularly about layers. The Scene view can show different layers than your main camera is set to see. Check that they match. Also, I note that your hierarchy shows eight "Bullet" objects, but I only see seven in the Scene view. Might be worth a moment to find out where the eighth one is. Maybe that will tell you something useful. Could you also maybe open the prefab and show us what the Inspector displays?

Comment: BugFinder the problem is that I already did everything you said, the script just spawn a bullet right in front of the player but even when falling down with no bg they don't show up

Comment: Are your bullets the yellow orbs? Because I think I actually do see them on the left side of your game screen, all bundled up together? https://gyazo.com/a54d9e7c3bb3ed2263eb607133973fd0

Comment: Have you looked at what I suggested? is the layer of prefabs in the list of culling of your main camera?

Comment: yes, I tried everything that you guys told me but anything seems to work

Comment: is your playerattack script attached to your camera? That is what only I can think of as you say they are instantiated at camera position.

Comment: If you are still having issues, you need to start showing us some of the answers to questions, like if you hide the player and buildings etc and leave only the instantiated items can you find them in the scene view while its paused?  as Remy says are they they yellow dots on the left? we need to see what you see

Answer (score -2):

The prefabs get instantiated correctly. As others suggested as well, the best way to find "lost" objects in your game is to shoot some stuff, pause the game, go into scene view, turn on 3D mode and double click one of the prefabs in the hierarchy. The camera will take you straight to your object.

Comment: The problem is that the object exist in the game tab but don't show up. I tryed to put on the bullet prefab a CircleCollider2D, the result is that the Player can collide with them but don't see them. It can be a strange bug or something that i made.
Thanks a lot for trying to help me

Comment: Probably your camera isn't drawing them. Please share more screenshots of your prefabs' inspector and camera's